# Поддерживает ли linux kernel планшеты-трансформеры (драйвера клавиатуры, видео, wi-fi, камер)?

Tags: android, linux, железо, драйвер, tablet

Хочу поставить на него Debian.

**Обновление**

Да забыл, простите. ASUS Transformer Pad TF103CG хочу купить и поставить на него Debian. Плюс кроме драйверов я не знаю отсутствует ли там перманентная блокировка UEFI (или BIOS, но навряд ли - он старый же). Или проще купить компактный ноутбук?

Comment: причем тут Android?

Comment: Планшет с android продаётся

Comment: а почему вы сразу об этом не написали?

Comment: в дебиане обычно идут более старые драйвера, чем в той же убунте. Поэтому, я бы начинал с убунты. Тем более, что там есть проект по созданию убунты под планшеты и телефоны.

Лучше купить нормальный ноут 11-13 дюймов и поставить туда нормальную ось, например, генту.

Comment: Вас понял, благодарю!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в дебиане обычно идут более старые драйвера, чем в той же убунте. Поэтому, я бы начинал с убунты. Тем более, что там есть [проект по созданию убунты](http://www.ubuntu.com/tablet) под планшеты и телефоны. Убунта - это просто дебиан с свеженьким софтом и некоторыми "улучшениями" от Canonical.

Но лучше купить нормальный ноут 11-13 дюймов и поставить туда нормальную ось, например, генту. Есть хорошие ноуты, которые почти как планшеты. К примеру, я одно время присматривался к [lenovo yoga](http://shop.lenovo.com/ua/ua/laptops/lenovo/yoga/).

UEFI можно разблокировать (то есть отключить проверку сертификата или вообще переключиться на старый добрый биос) на большинстве x86-64 платформах. На ARM платформах обычно нельзя и только через Secure Boot.

Answer (score 0):

На **ASUS TF700T** есть рабочие, проверенные мною порты Ubuntu и Lubuntu. Причём даже с поддержкой мультибута!

Авось, [тема на XDA по портированию](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2387133) окажется полезной. Работает клавиатура, тач и всё-всё-всё.

А на **TF300T** даже Xubuntu 14.04 [портировали](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=57529347&postcount=15) с [патчем для дока](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=58435538&postcount=623).